# Определение типа придаточного предложения в части СПП

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

> **"...возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву так, как взяли Смоленск..."**

В придаточной части *"как взяли Смоленск"* придаточное предложение является изъяснительным или обстоятельственным?
Склоняюсь ко второму варианту, но не уверена.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> но не уверена...

А почему не уверены? Какой вопрос вы задаёте к придаточному?

> задаю вопрос - как? (вопрос обстоятельства) На 99% уверена, что
>   придаточное обстоятельственное Верно?

Верно.

Comment: задаю вопрос - как? (вопрос обстоятельства)
На 99% уверена, что придаточное обстоятельственное
Верно?

Answer (score 0):

Князь Андрей, думавший, что ему было **все равно**, возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву, **так**, как взяли Смоленск, внезапно остановился в своей речи от неожиданной судороги, схватившей его за горло.

**Интересное предложение.** Кажется, что это обычное придаточное образа действия: возьмут Москву так, как взяли Смоленск, но тогда **смысл сообщения неясен.**

Можно предположить, что здесь инверсия местоимения "так" (так все равно, как), тогда это обстоятельство степени + сравнение, но в этом случае **нужна дополнительная запятая.**

И тогда это параллельное подчинение изъяснительного и обстоятельственного предложений.

Comment: Вера, а как понять: ''так все равно, как''? что ему было так все равно, возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву...?

Comment: Я думаю, это "в такой степени же всё равно, как было все равно при взятии Смоленска". А иначе смысл непонятен: возьмут так же (таким образом, таким способом), как взяли Смоленск? Поэтому вопрос о семантике предложения и возможной запятой мне кажется интересным. Вообще говоря, при  разборе вид обстоятельственного придаточного надо указывать обязательно, иначе это будет формальный разбор, не определяющий понимание структуры предложения. А в заданном вопросе, как и в полученном ответе, эта тема никак не затрагивается.

Comment: Вера, а почему Вы не допускаете вариант: так же (таким образом, таким способом), как взяли Смоленск?

Comment: Да, наверное, здесь имеется в виду следующий  факт: 6 (18) августа маршал Даву вступил в город, напоминавший собою, по свидетельству самих французов, извержение Везувия, «огромный костер, покрытый трупами и ранеными», «пылающий ад». Смоленск горел так, что в нем из 2250 жилых домов уцелело не более 350, а почти все его 15 тыс. жителей ушли вместе с армией – не осталось и одной тысячи.